# JasperReports is slow in java swing

Tags: java, jasper-reports

While executing this code require near about 30 seconds to display.

```
DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
        "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String connection_string = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nursery";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";

        Connection connection;
        File file = new File("D:/reports/sowing.jrxml");

        try {
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(file);
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("reportTitle", "Hello Report World");
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            System.out.println("IN the window");
            Class.forName(driverName);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_string, username, password);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
});
```

**Is there any solution to execute as fast as possible?**

Comment: For large report you can try the [Virtualizers](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/virtualizer/index.html#virtualizer). You can also make the *DB* turning

Comment: Its not a large report.. just a simple one page report. Is there any extra plugin require to display the report ?

Comment: I'm not sure about a fix for this. But I found the delay occurs when calling "JRXmlLoader.load()" method for the first time. May be there is a way to pre-initialize the JRXmlLoader so after that there won't occure any delays